# Very simple user authentication php

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I am another virgin coder and I am having trouble creating a very, very simple user authentication system. Contrary to best practice, this is a small project and security is not a matter of concern.

I want to create a username and password, which is to be encrypted and stored in the database. Then, a login form, then directed to the target page. I am not concerned with staying logged in for sessions; it can be one and done thing in order to access a single page at a time. Very rudimentary, but I'm still unable figure out on my own...

User input with the hashed pass from createuser.html, FORM.php isnt not being sent to the database.

I have some code here...

CREATE ADMIN:

```html
....

    <div class="body-content">
      <div class="module">
        <h1>Create Admin</h1>
        <form class="form" action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="alert alert-error"></div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username" required />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
        
     ....
```

FORM.php

```html
if (!$con)
 {die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() ); }


$var_user = $_POST['username'];
$var_pass = $_POST['password'];

//encrypt the password
//Grab the password from form data sent via POST

//encrypt the password
$encPassword = password_hash($var_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 

$query = "INSERT INTO users(id, username, password)
VALUES ('id', '$var_user', '$encPassword')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $query))
 {echo "User created" . "<br>";}
else
 { die('SQL Error: ' . mysql_error($con) ); }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

LOGIN:

```html
.....
  <form name="login" method="post" action="verify.php">
    <table width="450px">
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="100" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
      <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="100" size="30">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
      <input type="login" value="Login" name="Login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
.....
```

verify.php

```html
<?php 
// $encPassword is the hashed password value from our database
// $postPassword is the password from our login form
     if (password_verify($postPassword, $encPassword )) 
{         echo 'Password is valid!';     } else {         echo 'Invalid password.';     }     ?>
```

I know it's not much, and I am missing a part in verify to check the password with the connected username. I just really need some help here my human friends. Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You want to encrypt the datas?

Comment: Are you asking us to write it for you, or what exactly is your issue? Btw, what's the difference between the first two forms?

Comment: @hungrykoala I wrote code to the best of my ability, to create a new user, hash the password, then login to a page using those credentials. but it is not working and I am looking for some pro help.

Comment: Where are you getting `$_POST['id']` from? Also... Where is the issue? You have not made that very clear

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I totally missed that when I reviewed my question, I added the FORM.php code I have. The problem is that when I try to create a new user, it is not added to the database with the hashed pass.. Secondly, I was hoping to be guided with the code I have for login, VERIFY.php so the user input checks in with the user/hashpass in the database and logs into the page.

Comment: Good point @Samuel ... I removed that line from my code

Comment: 1. Remove the `id` column from your insert. Right now, you're adding the string "id" as the id. If that field is an autoincrement-field (which it should be), MySQL will solve that column on it's own. 2. You are _wide open_ to SQL Injections and should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.

Comment: You're also mixing the `mysqli` and `mysql` API's. To get errors for failing queries, you should use `mysqli_error($con)`.

Comment: you `verify.php` should work. as long as you retrieve `$encPassword` from the database. For your form.php just do what they said and remove `id`